# How can I implement virtual attribute hierarchies?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a Python object which supports the following?

```
obj = ...
obj.abc.def = 123
print(obj.abc.def)
x = obj.abc.ghi(1,2,3)
```

The point is that `obj` should not contain all the attributes (which could be numerous, and possibly not known in advance), but instead end with a call to some sort of handler, i.e. `handler(obj,'get','abc','def')`, etc. to perform the requested action and return its result.

What I'm after is a convenient notation for interactive use, with the dot notation to access a specific detail of the object, without using objects of objects of objects.

I understand `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, and I've read about *descriptors* in Python 3, And maybe I should look into making `__dict__` a mapping object, but I'm running afoul on the open-ended nesting involved when faced with `a.b.c` style sub-attributes.

Comment: To what end? Why not just use dictionaries?

Comment: The handler will connect to an external service. I can't populate the dictionary up front with all possible attributes & sub-attributes. The dot notation is easier interactively than typing `obj['abc']['def']`. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking ...

Comment: You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but you're no more blocked on populating the dictionary keys up front than you are the instance attributes.

Comment: Aha, thanks. I'll need to ponder on how this can be nested. Each attribute, once used, gets set to a `defaultdict`, which then gets repeated for sub-attributes? How to get control once the nesting ends, since `x = obj.abc.def` will return a defaultdict. Perhaps `x = obj.abc.def()` to perform the end step.

Answer (score 1):

A tree structure can be defined using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)
```

This can be used to create arbitrarily nested keys on the fly:

```
t = tree()
t['a']['b']['c'] = 123
```

Working with attribute access, we can use `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` to delegate calls to an underlying dict of a similar recursive form:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__setattr__('t', defaultdict(Tree))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.t[name]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.t[name] = value
```

Now attributes can be generated on the fly by accessing them:

```
t = Tree()
t.a.b.c = 123
```